# Как узнать тип входящей строки?

Tags: типы, java

Нужно сравнить тип элемента, но не знаю как.

В листе находятся номера и строки вперемешку.

```
for(int i= 0; i<stringList.size(); i++) {
   if(stringList.get(i).equals(String.class)) {
      System.out.println("Name" + " " + stringList.get(i));
   } else {
      System.out.println("Number" + " " + stringList.get(i));
   }
}
```

Comment: instanceof

Comment: для начала, Вы должны себе ответить на вопрос, "а чем строка отличается числа, которое представлено строкой?". Правильный ответ такой - первое нельзя преобразовать в строку, а второе можно. Дальше читаем, к примеру, [такое](http://www.dotnetperls.com/parseint) и пишем код.

Comment: вот интересно, все плюсуют instanceof, а автору то он точно не нужен:)

Comment: Не ясно что хочет автор, но в коде он использует String.class, поэтому логично предположить, что он хочет узнать тип объекта. Хотя ему нужно узнать, что записано в строке. TextUtils.isDigitsOnly() поможет, например, или вручную определение написать. Но тут у нас, вроде бы, не делают работу за человека.

Comment: да абсолютно ясно, что хочет человек. А то, что он использует - мало чего он использует.

Comment: @KoVadim да я некропостер!

Answer (score 0):

Если в исходных данных только целые положительные числа

```
for(String str : stringList) {
   if(str.chars().allMatch(Character::isDigit)) {
      System.out.println("Number" + " " + str);
   } else {
      System.out.println("Name" + " " + str);
   }
}
```

Иначе потребуется более многословный вариант

```
public static boolean isNumeric(String str) {
    DecimalFormatSymbols currentLocaleSymbols = DecimalFormatSymbols.getInstance();
    char minusSign = currentLocaleSymbols.getMinusSign();

    if (!Character.isDigit(str.charAt(0)) && str.charAt(0) != minusSign) return false;

    boolean isDecimalSeparatorFound = false;
    char decimalSeparator = currentLocaleSymbols.getDecimalSeparator();

    for (char c : str.substring(1).toCharArray()) {
        if (!Character.isDigit(c)) {
            if (c == decimalSeparator && !isDecimalSeparatorFound) {
                isDecimalSeparatorFound = true;
                continue;
            }
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

for(String str : stringList) {
   if(isNumeric(str)) {
      System.out.println("Number" + " " + str);
   } else {
      System.out.println("Name" + " " + str);
   }
}
```

[Отсюда](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1102891/how-to-check-if-a-string-is-numeric-in-java)

Или так, как вам подсказывал @KoVadim

```
for(String str : stringList) {
    try {
        Double.parseDouble(str);
        System.out.println("Number" + " " + str);
    } catch (NumberFormatException exc) {
        System.out.println("Name" + " " + str);
    }
}
```

Ещё лучше не изобретать велосипед, а взять [Apache Commons Lang](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/), в котором есть [StringUtils.isNumeric()](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#isNumeric-java.lang.CharSequence-).